# apply jquery ui spinner to dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I'd like to apply jquery-ui spinner to dynamically added elements.

--html code--

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="eachBox1"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="eachBox2"></div>
...
</table>
```

-- jquery code --

```
    $.ajax({
             ...
             success: function (items) {
                 $.each(items.d, function (idx, item) {
                      $('#eachBox'+idx).html
                       (   ...
                          '<input type="text" id="qty'+idx+'" value="1"/>'
                           ...
                       )
                  }
              }
     })
```

and i want to apply jquery-ui spinner to every element that name start with qty..
so I tried

```
$(document).on("load","[id^=qty]" function () {
    $(this).spinner();
});
```

But it doesn't work. If i change `load` event to `click`, it works.
But it isn't what I want.
Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$.ajax({
         ...
         success: function (items) {
             $.each(items.d, function (idx, item) {
                  $('#eachBox'+idx).html
                   (   ...
                      '<input type="text" id="qty'+idx+'" value="1"/>'
                       ...
                   )
              }
              $("[id^=qty]").spinner();
          }
 })
```

---

Just added the `.spinner()` into the `success: function(){}`, in order to apply `spinner()` only once elements are created.

Answer (score 0):

i think , there is an comma missed in your code.

> ```
>  $(document).on("load","[id^=qty]", function () {
>                 $(this).spinner();
>             });
> ```

what about this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("[id^=qty]").spinner();
});
```

Comment: well.. that's my mistake. it doesn't work though thanks.

Comment: check the modification

Comment: I already tried it. can't solve it though, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax({
             ...
             success: function (items) {
                 $.each(items.d, function (idx, item) {
                      $('#eachBox'+idx).html
                       (   ...
                          '<input type="text" id="qty'+idx+'" value="1"/>'
                           ...
                       )
                      $('#qty'+idx).spinner();
                  }
              }
     })
```

i hope this will work